# How to nest Grails controller paths

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I know it is possible to do something like this:

Controller foo with action bar can be accessed by (1):

```
/appname/foo/bar
```

And it can be rewritten using URL mappings - e.g like this:

```
"/foobar/foo/$action"(controller: "foo")
```

And then access it via (2):

```
/appname/foobar/foo/bar
```

But it is still possible to access it via (1). This is of course because of the default URL mapping:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"()
```

But I would rather not delete this, because this basically means I have to manually write mappings to every other controller/action that follows the default pattern.

It is possible to obtain url-patterns for specific controller/actions like (2) without using URL mappings? If not, is there an easy way to "exclude" controllers from the default mapping closure?

Comment: I think I understand what you're after, Hoof. I don't think you can achieve it precisely as you want. The default /$controller/$action/$id mapping will have to become /<specific-string>/$action/$id where <specific-string> = "foo". It's a bit of a pain in the neck but I actually have to do something similar. Your other option would be to keep the default Grails rule and prefix everything that needs to break that rule with something in the path.

Comment: Well. The latter suggestion - "Your other option would be to keep the default Grails rule and prefix everything that needs to break that rule with something in the path" - how would you do that? I want to keep the default URL mapping, but break it for certain controllers that should only be accessible within a prefix... E.g. foo controller only accessible via foobar/foo :)

Comment: I'll post an answer with some example code. I don't understand your requirement entirely but I'll show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is to change the default mapping, in a way to exclude the whished special controller URL.

```
class UrlMappings {

  static myExcludes = ["foo"]

  static mappings = {
    "/foobar/foo/$action"(controller: "foo") // your special Mapping

    // the rewritten default mapping rule
    "/$aController/$aAction?/$id?"{ 
        controller = { (params.aController in UrlMappings.myExcludes) ? "error" : params.aController }
        action = { (params.aController in UrlMappings.myExcludes) ? "notFound" : params.aAction }
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        } 
     }
  }
}
```

For the rewritten default rule you have to prevent usage of default variable names $controller and $action. Instead of error/notFound you are also able to redirect to other locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your rule breaking scenario more specific than the Grails default $controller/$action?$id? pattern, then the default can be left as is and will apply to everything outside of your exception pattern. I made a quick Person domain and performed a generate-all. Then I made a BreakRuleController just by itself.

> ```
> class UrlMappings {
>
> static mappings = {
>
>     "/b/$action?/$someVariable?"(controller: "breakRule")
>
>     "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
>         constraints {
>             // apply constraints here
>         }
>     }
>
>     "/"(view:"/index")
>     "500"(view:'/error')  
>    }
> ```
>
> }

With this UrlMapping, if you access the URI "/b/foo/stackoverflow" it will print "Breaking Rules foo: stackoverflow". If you go to "/b", it will print "Breaking Rules index".

Then if you go to the standard Person URI's, all your default Grails scaffolding works fine also (create, edit, etc.) because that gets mapped to the typical "$controller/$action?/$id?" pattern.

> class BreakRuleController {
>
> ```
>    def index() {
>        print "Breaking Rules index"
>    }
>
>    def foo(String someVariable) {
>        print "Breaking Rules foo: " + someVariable
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: But I can still go to "/breakRule/**" - can I not? Above example is, as far as I can see, the exact same as my example (2)?

Comment: Could you maybe clarify your question?  I don't understand precisely what you're looking to achieve.  I think I'm a bit lost in foo, bar, foobar.

Comment: In your own example, it is possible to reach "/b/foo/stackoverflow" because of the specific URL mapping. However! It is still possible to just goto "/breakRule/foo/stackoverflow". The latter because of the default mapping. I wan't to avoid the latter without having to write EVERY other URL mapping manually - that is, removing the default general dynamic URL mapping. Get it?